# I want to know is there any way represent a negative entity as a positive entity while we print on console in java?

Tags: java

Usually i would use a statement as follows to make a negative entity positive while printing, ex lets juts say Selling_price =4400 and Cost_price = 4500, so following statement prints $100 loss instead of $-100:

```
System.out.println("Seller made Rs"+-1*PR+" of loss")
```

Is there any function that can do this or is there any other variation to this i can perform?

Comment: `"Seller made Rs"+(-PR)+" of loss"`

Comment: Do you just mean Math.abs(x) ?

Comment: @khelwood: Yeah thats another way i know but thanks.

Comment: @Bret: I dont know about Math.abs(x), i m just a rookie learning java

Comment: Seriously -1, i mean even for asking questions. WOW!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for [Math.abs()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/number_abs.htm).

```
System.out.println("Seller made Rs"+Math.abs(PR)+" of loss")
```

Check [Math API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html)

Comment: Do i have to use any import statement to load a particular class in the program.

Comment: Nope, Math is part of java as String or Integer... You can use it *for free* ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Math.abs()` method. In your case it can be something like: `System.out.println("Seller made Rs" + Math.abs(PR) + " of loss")`

Comment: Thanks, i will try the vaiation

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println("Seller made Rs"+ (PR > 0 ? PR : -PR) +" of loss")
```

It wouldn't exactly be a loss if `PR > 0` I suppose. 
You also could use an if-else statement to determine if it's a "loss" or "profit".

Comment: I m using if for that but i just wanted to know if a negative number can be represented in other way or is there any other function i can use